# What does "justify resource" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I just saw a sentence looks like this:

> The strategy sheds light on the future endeavor and justifies
>   resources.

I have no idea what "justifies resources" means. Doesn't justify mean prove? What does it mean by saying prove resources?

Well, I use an [online dictonary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/justify?s=t) to check the word justify. I think 5a, as a verb, to show or to prove, is the only reasonable definition under such circumstance.

Comment: Is  _to prove_ really the only definition of the verb _to justify_ in your English dictionary? Can you tell us what _English_ dictionary you consulted? Please use the [edit] link to tell us what it is about your dictionary's definitions of _justify_ and _resource_ that you don't understand. This will permit us to offer useful guidance.

Comment: Have you considered _"to show a satisfactory reason or excuse for something done"_? It's important to read many different definitions, and to _think_ about these definitions. There at least a score of useful online English dictionaries. How many did you consult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"justify resources" means to demonstrate the benefit of spending or allocating various resources such as time, personnel, materials, space, money on the endeavor.

In most instances, "justify resources" equates to "not wasting money".